# NGRX router-store: selectCurrentRoute selector undefined

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-routing, ngrx-store

I'm trying to use the selectCurrentRoute selector, but I only get undefined.

```
export interface AppState {
  router: RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl>
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
  router: routerReducer
};

export const selectRouterState = createFeatureSelector<RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl>>('router');
export const { selectCurrentRoute } = getSelectors(selectRouterState);
export const getCurrentRoute = createSelector(selectRouterState, selectCurrentRoute);
------    
this.store
      .select(routerFromSelector.getCurrentRoute)
      .subscribe((route) => console.log(route));
```

core.module.ts

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers), 
StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
serializer: CustomSerializer,
}),
      
providers: [{ provide: RouterStateSerializer, useClass: CustomSerializer }],
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'
})],
```

my state:

```
router -> state -> 
url():"/person/1"
params -> id():"1"
queryParams():
navigationId():1
```

Answer (score 1):

The default router key that's used in the store is `router` (https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/875adb3a99ba394f58d107c6223578326887c74e/modules/router-store/src/router_store_module.ts#L98).

This means you need to change your state key `routerState` to `router`, or you can configure the router key in `StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot()`. (https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store/configuration)

```
StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
      stateKey: 'routerState'
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed my routerState to router but still get undefined in my select. I will update my original post with the new state.

Comment: this.store.select(routerFromSelector.selectUrl) is working, but it's the only one

Comment: `export interface RouterStateUrl {
  url: string;
  params: Params;
  queryParams: Params;
}`
am I missing something necessary here, in order to get the selectors working?
I'm using the custom route serializer: 
https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store/configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lazy loading, you will need to change the serializer (The default one won't work), so you need to get the parent + child route parameters into the state, check: https://medium.com/simars/ngrx-router-store-reduce-select-route-params-6baff607dd9

After you do so, triple verify the data ended up in the state, you can use the Redux devtools extension to make sure it ended up in the state.

Finally, if all is good, write your own selectors that match how data in the state looks like, so don't use the default getSelectors as it might not work